# Immediate Window inserts line breaks in output

Tags: .net, visual-studio, immediate-window

I find myself debugging REST services lately and that involves visualising a lot of JSON.

When I have receive a JSON string and attempt to print it to the Immediate Window using the command `?jsonString,nq`, the string is printed with a line break every 1026 characters.

This is annoying because it means every time I print, copy and paste the string I have to find/replace the CRLFs so that the string is valid JSON.

Is there a way to get devenv to print the string without these line breaks?
Is  there some hidden setting for the "width" of the Immediate Window "terminal"?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this behaviour of wrapping at 1024 chars in the immediate window cannot be changed. You could try using the watch window or Shift+F9 after selecting the variable for an instant watch.

Comment: Thanks, the Watch/Locals/QuickWatch Window has the Text Visualiser popup which is not ideal (mouse clicks to bring up a modal dialog) but it does have a setting for long line wrap which can be unchecked.

Comment: Yes, it's harder to work with but being at the whim of Microsoft's design decisions, we beggars can't be choosers : ) .